# How to change the value of a PayPal form input to a vlaue given by the user by a text input

Tags: jquery, forms, input, paypal

I want to make a Store using PayPal. I want the user to give their In-Game Username in a text-field, after that I want the value of the input named "ign" to be the same as the given value by the user. Why I want it like this and not a text field in the form, is because I want the user to only fill in his Username once and still be able to buy more than only one item and I don't want 30 text fields that all ask for the same thing. This is what I have now and I know it is not working but I'm searching for somebody who can say which Javascript I need to use or HTML. Don't mind the Capital words in the form. I have them right in my own website.

```
<script>$("input.txtPlayerName").val($("#PlayerName").val());</script>

<input id="PlayerName" type="text" placeholder="Player Name" >

<form method="POST" action="http://YOUR-STORE-URL-HERE/cart/directpay">
    <input type="hidden" name="gateway" value="GATEWAY-NAME-HERE" />
    <input type="hidden" name="package" value="PACKAGE-ID-HERE" />
    <input type="hidden" class="txtPlayerName" name="ign" value="" />
    <input type="submit" value="Purchase" />
</form>
```

Thanks for reading and maybe answering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set it in the change event:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#PlayerName").change(function() {
        $("input.txtPlayerName").val($(this).val());
    });
});
</script>

<input id="PlayerName" type="text" placeholder="Player Name" >

<form method="POST" action="http://YOUR-STORE-URL-HERE/cart/directpay">
    <input type="hidden" name="gateway" value="GATEWAY-NAME-HERE" />
    <input type="hidden" name="package" value="PACKAGE-ID-HERE" />
    <input type="hidden" class="txtPlayerName" name="ign" value="" />
    <input type="submit" value="Purchase" />
</form>
```

Comment: Can you put this in my existing code please? I don't really know how to put it into the code.

Comment: @user1610226 see now, just replace your script tag with mine.

Comment: This is a little bit off topic, but do you know how to put Javascript into worpdress.

Comment: @user1610226 like you put any other html, what I posted is html.. Where did you place it before?

Comment: I just placed it into the HTML editor and the script part got <p> tags in front of it.

Comment: @user1610226 technically it doesn't matter, the script should run regardless. http://jsfiddle.net/SkCsL/

Comment: @user1610226 you didn't copypaste it exactly. You have `$(#PlayerName).val()` I have `$(this).val()`. You either need `$(this).val()` OR `$("#PlayerName").val()` notice the *quotes* (`"`)

Comment: @user1610226 you have not included jQuery on your page. `ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined`

Comment: @user1610226 You can accept the answer by clicking the checkmark on the left of my answer body.